# Return and display data, but with condition

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, redux-toolkit

I have this "api" and through it a group of users is returned, then I display the users in a table, and the form of the data that is returned based on the written code is:

[image]

And as it is clear in the picture, there are two variables within the data that have been returned, the first is “isActive” and the second is “isVerified”, and these two variables are either “false” or “true”.

The problem is that I want to return only the data in which the value of the two variables is true.

That is, data is returned from the backend, and this data is a group of users, and each user has two values "isActive" and "isVerified", and either I have these values "true" and either "false", but what is required is that I want to return the data and Displayed in table only when these two values are true.

How can I solve the problem?

```
export const getUsers = createAsyncThunk(
  "usersRequests/getUsersRequests",
  async (routeParams, { getState }) => {
    routeParams = routeParams || getState().usersApp.users.routeParams;
    const response = await axios
      .get("/users/for-admin", {
        params: routeParams,
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    const usersRequestsData = response.data.data;
    console.log("data inside Slice:", usersRequestsData);
    return usersRequestsData;
  }
);
```

Comment: Can't you just change it in backend or add query to it so you can change based on request?

Comment: Clearly, much better things, use a query in your call if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to add a query to your URL like so /?active=true&verified=true, and of course, add parsing and then logic to your backend, or you could create a separate route.

If the first solution isn't perfect for you, you can filter it in your front-end, I don't think filtering in async thunk is a good approach, you should filter it in your reducer.

```
const usersSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'users',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(getUsers.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
      state.users = payload.filter(u => u.isActive === true && u.isVerified === true);
    });
  },
});
```

Comment: I don't want say 'my solution is better, really', but, for my understanding, the middleware work is fetching and prepare the data, so, if you every time just need the value with condition, it's better to prepare your data before process on your state. It's an opinion, if you have any opposition, I ready to talk.

Comment: But sure, isActive && isVerified is better syntax than isActive === true..., same as if(a) equivalent to if(a === true)

Comment: I made the syntax like this so it is clear for her, nonetheless `isActive && isVerified` is better, shorter syntax.

Comment: Ah, yeah, good way for explain.

Answer (score 0):

Just before the .catch, use a .then to prepare your data with a return filter, something like :

```
.then((res) => res.filter((item) => item.valueToEvaluate1 && item.valueToEvaluate2))
```

The doc to understand filter https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Good ?

Comment: is this correct? then(
        (res) =>
          res.data.data.filter(
            (item) => item.isActive == true && item.isVerified == true
          ),
        console.log("res: ", res)
      )

Comment: if you use && (and), you don't need precise 'true' because if is expression false the 'and' is false, same thing like 'if (a) equivalent to if (a === true) because if check if expression is true. You need to precise if you want check a value like string :  a === 'toto' && b === 'tata'.

Comment: I'm not sure to explain correctly, it's difficult to explain, you want to see if an expression is true so, if your value is true, you just need check the variable, not needed to precise === true